# Styling the content of Lightbox2 popups

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6, lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2 to display a node within a Lightbox iframe popup (using `rel="lightframe"` within a link).

Is there a way to pipe CSS into this iframe so I can style the contents the way I want them?

(I actually don't understand why using a rule like `iframe body {font-size:1em}` doesn't work, but that's just me being stupid... :-/)

I'm guessing I need to run a JavaScript function after the Lightbox has loaded that will add the CSS. Will that work?

Comment: what do you want to do with the lightbox?

Comment: The body tag within the iframe is inheriting a few rules from the styles applied to the 'main' body tag. I just want to override a couple of these (background-color for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with styling an **iframe** is a little headache, or at-least that is what my designer told me ;)

The easiest solution `would be to add the styles directly in the template of the node type` that you are trying to display in lightbox. This would work if you lightbox is the only place where you are displaying that node.

This is a working solution but not an elegant one. Would appreciate if somebody can come with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Cheers. Unfortunately I'm needing to display the node both normally and within a Lightbox. :(

Comment: I think I can get away with only viewing the node in a Lightbox in this instance, but it'd definitely be cool to know how to do it in other ways as well.